# saving form in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I was wondering how could I retrieve the data from SQL server compact database that I just saved and insert it into textbox of newly created form. The source code is not complete, I just wanted to save space. Connection is fine, and I'm able to add data into database in the actual program. I just would like to know how to retrieve it and put it into textbox of newly created form. This is done in WinForms.Thank you!

```
    public void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO tbl1(Name) VALUES (@Name, @LastName)", conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", t1.Text);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }


     private void b2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {    
        Form form2 = new Form();        
        form2.Show();

       t3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 35);
       t3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(85, 15);
       //access database and insert data into textbox
       t3.Text = ?
       form2.Controls.Add(t3);

    }
```

Comment: Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET?  All can use C# and all have a different syntax.

Comment: Just FYI, "incomplete" source code is actually a good thing on Stack Overflow. Always post only the relevant parts of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's not to hard to just get a value from the database, something like this should suit your needs:

```
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl1(Name) WHERE name = @Name AND last_name = @LastName", conn);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Hank");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "Hill");
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

t1.Text = reader.GetString(0);
t2.Text = reader.GetString(1);
```

Comment: I suggest you do some research into the SQL language, and the SqlDataReader

Comment: No problem, but actually there is a not so good thing I want to point out in my code. Be careful when using the * character in a select like this because you don't know what order the columns will come back in, I should have done something like "SELECT name, last_name FROM ..."

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, start at the official docs. See this sample, on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226134(v=sql.80).aspx

They show there a couple of SQL commands like SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE. You know how to insert, so you are now interested in the SELECT part. See how they use data reader and try that for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983340(v=VS.80).aspx
Please also check codeplex.com for additional examples/projects